# How to modify a dataframe with conditions for each ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this (its a pretty big one)

| id | pen | usd | PEN/USD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 0 | pen/usd |
| 1 | 0 | 20 | pen/usd |
| 1 | 15 | 0 | pen/usd |
| 1 | 25 | 0 | pen/usd |
| 1 | 35 | 0 | pen/usd |
| 1 | 45 | 0 | pen/usd |
| 2 | 0 | 15 | usd |
| 2 | 0 | 5 | usd |
| 2 | 0 | 5 | usd |
| 3 | 15 | 0 | pen |
| 3 | 10 | 0 | pen |
| 4 | 55 | 0 | pen/usd |
| 4 | 70 | 0 | pen/usd |
| 4 | 0 | 60 | pen/usd |

Thanks for your answer. My question was how to create the column "PEN/USD". Each id tells us if it has an amount in "pen" or "usd" depending on the column. For example: for id "1" there are 6 occurrences. 5 in "pen" and 1 in "usd". Therefore, it has "pen/usd". Even if you have only one amount of one of the two, it should be "pen/usd" in the column "PEN/USD".

Comment: What if both pen and usd columns have 0 in all rows for a particular id? What should be the output then?

Comment: If an ID exists, it is because a pen or usd record exists. In other words, it always has at least one of the two. 
Thanks for the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) followed by a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```py
totals = df2.groupby('id', as_index=False)['pen', 'usd'].sum()
print(totals)

    id  pen usd
0   1   125 20
1   2   0   25
2   3   25  0
3   4   125 60

# Assing values to 'PEN/USD' 
totals.loc[(totals['pen']>0) & (totals['usd']>0), 'PEN/USD'] = 'pen/usd'
totals.loc[(totals['pen']==0) & (totals['usd']>0), 'PEN/USD'] = 'pen'
totals.loc[(totals['pen']>0) & (totals['usd']==0), 'PEN/USD'] = 'usd'

df.merge(totals[['id', 'PEN/USD']], on='id')


    id  pen usd PEN/USD
0   1   5   0   pen/usd
1   1   0   20  pen/usd
2   1   15  0   pen/usd
3   1   25  0   pen/usd
4   1   35  0   pen/usd
5   1   45  0   pen/usd
6   2   0   15  pen
7   2   0   5   pen
8   2   0   5   pen
9   3   15  0   usd
10  3   10  0   usd
11  4   55  0   pen/usd
12  4   70  0   pen/usd
13  4   0   60  pen/usd
```

Comment: Too interactive a solution. I have a question about the "counts" function. How did you get it? I think that refers to "totals".

Comment: Sorry, it is indeed "totals". I have edited the answer. What do you mean by "too interactive"?

Comment: I meant that the solution you gave is very easy to understand. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to check if an ID contains both currencies or just one of the two. I used `any()` to check this.

```
temp = """
1   5   0   pen/usd
1   0   20  pen/usd
1   15  0   pen/usd
1   25  0   pen/usd
1   35  0   pen/usd
1   45  0   pen/usd
2   0   15  usd
2   0   5   usd
2   0   5   usd
3   15  0   pen
3   10  0   pen
4   55  0   pen/usd
4   70  0   pen/usd
4   0   60  pen/usd
"""
temp2 = re.sub(r"\t", r",", temp)
temp2 = io.StringIO(temp) 
df = pd.read_csv(temp2, sep="\t",header=None)
df = df.rename(columns={0:"id",1:"pen",2:"usd",3:"PEN/USD"})

df.groupby(["id","PEN/USD"]).any().reset_index()

    id  PEN/USD  pen    usd
0   1   pen/usd  True   True
1   2   usd      False  True
2   3   pen      True   False
3   4   pen/usd  True   True
```